# set item in select list to be selected

Tags: jquery, select

I have a select list like so:

```
<select id="drpColours">
<option value="" selected="selected">Choose color</option>
<option value="1">black</option>
<option value="2">BLUE</option>
</select>
```

I can I set the selected item based on the text item and not the value. So if i pass "Blue" to a function, I want the function to set the 3rd item in the list to be selected.

I am using jquery for this.

Comment: It's not a jQuery related issue, you have to generate HTML the way you want and assign whatever values you want...

Comment: You could possibly loop through the values in the dropdown, converting them to all lowercase, and checking which has the same value. The options should have meaningful values though, such as black, blue, etc. Also, shouldn't have some options all lowercase and others all caps. Doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
function setColor( color ) {
    $('#drpColours option').each(function() {
        this.selected = ( this.text.toLowerCase() === color.toLowerCase() );
    });
}
setColor('BLUE');
```

It does a case-insensitive match. If you want case sensitivity, then remove both `.toLowerCase()` calls.

Or here's an alternate version of the same thing:

```
function setColor( color ) {
    $('#drpColours option').attr('selected', function() {
        return ( this.text.toLowerCase() === color.toLowerCase() );
    });
}

setColor('BLUE');
```

Comment: Just for fun: this jsPerf test (http://jsperf.com/set-selected-option-based-on-contents) shows that the first version is faster.

Comment: @Dan - Thanks for the test. :o) It doesn't surprise me too much. A while back I was looking at what jQuery does when you pass a function to some of these methods that can accept one, and as I remember, there was a bit of extra work involved.